# Add foreign key in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Following images are my table structure and the relational view form in phpmyadmin

[image]

[image]

My question is how to add foreign key for 'org_id' column,
'org_id' is also an integer field and it's unsigned field but why it isn't allow to add a foreign key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**MySQL** forces you to index foreign key.

> MySQL requires indexes on foreign keys and referenced keys so that
>   foreign key checks can be fast and not require a table scan.

You can read more about foreign keys on MySQL documentation pages:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Answer (score 1):

Just had to figure this out for myself:

- Open the table you want to add foreign keys too.
- Click the Structure Tab
- Click the RELATION VIEW button just above the list of columns
- Enter data for in the Foreign key constraints box
- DO NOT index the column you want to make into a Foreign Key first.  This caused my creation attempts to fail

Answer (score 0):

org_id in parent table should be indexed, so just create index in parent table and then create foreign key.

Comment: orgs table that don't have org_id it as id column only and it is the primary key of orgs table

Comment: Picture will be clear if you provide "show create table table_name;" for both tables...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/11723585)

Comment: @VinothKrishnan Why isn't this an answer...?

Comment: Read the criteria's of [low quality posts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251820/what-are-the-criteria-for-low-quality-posts) and see the [discussions on meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/311076/delete-low-quality-post?lq=1)